# Switching monitors from an app

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, switch

I'd like to know if anybody out here knows if there's a way to **easily** switch between monitors from an app in Windows 7.

**The setup:** I have a laptop who's resolution is 1600 x 900 and a monitor which is 1920 x 1080.

**What I'd like to do:** When I plug my monitor in my laptop I'd like to be able to run a program (or a script), ideally just by clicking on an icon on the desktop or by typing a hotkey, that would switch the primary output form one monitor to the other.

I know I can do it manually by going in my display options, but this is very cumbersome and not an ideal solution. This is *not* the answer I'm looking for.

So, do you guys know any program that could do it?

Alternatively, being a programmer I could code it. So if anybody know what's the API for it (preferably in .Net) and a general "howto" to go along, that's a valid answer as well.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> = switch monitor

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> = resize window

... and many other shortcuts ;)

Comment: Okay... WOW!!!  I plug in the monitor, and HOP! The display is switched...  unplug it... It automagically switches back! I don't even need to use hotkeys! That's awesome! Thanks Wolfy!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Windows logo</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> switches an app to monitor left or right

from [My Digital Life - Windows 7 Keyboard Shortcuts (Accelerator Keys or Hotkeys) Full Listing](http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerator-keys-or-hotkeys-full-listing/)

It does have the behaviour you want on a Lenovo laptop without additional software (Intel HD 4000, win 7): as soon as I plug-in a second monitor (previously set to primary display) this monitor will become primary display and if I unplug the laptop monitor is used as primary display. I think windows saves a monitor set-up and recognizes it if the same (I don't know what this exactly means) monitor is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and above has this hotkey: Win+P. It is meant for projectors, but should work in most cases-